# "Имей в виду, что ... во-первых ... и во-вторых ..." - Нужно ли выделять вводные слова запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> **`textContent` и `innerText`**
>
> Когда достаточно `textContent`, используй `textContent`.  Когда нужно именно `innerText`, используй `innerText`, но имей в виду, что `innerText` во-первых медленнее (в некоторых тестах в 300 раз) и во-вторых в разных браузерах работает немного по-разному (потому что не стандартизировано).

> **`textContent` и `innerText`**
>
> Когда достаточно `textContent`, используй `textContent`.  Когда нужно именно `innerText`, используй `innerText`, но имей в виду, что `innerText`, во-первых, медленнее (в некоторых тестах в 300 раз) и, во-вторых, в разных браузерах работает немного по-разному (потому что не стандартизировано).

Первый вариант нравится, второй - нет. Пытаюсь понять, какой из них является пунктуационно-корректным.

В статьях в Интернете сказано, что вводные слова, если находятся в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, запятыми не выделяются. Но мои попытки понять, что же такое обособленный оборот, успехом не увенчались: всё очень сложно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Под обособленными оборотами понимаются конструкции (*обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения* - так у Розенталя), обособляемые в предложении по основаниям, не связанным с присутствием вводного слова.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=32

Упростим исходное предложение:

> Когда нужно именно А, используй Б, но имей в виду, что Б, во-первых,
> медленнее и, во-вторых, в разных браузерах работает немного
> по-разному.

Без искажения структуры предложения можно опустить "во-первых... во-вторых":

> Когда нужно именно А, используй Б, но имей в виду, что Б медленнее и в
> разных браузерах работает немного по-разному.

Видно, что в местах изъятия "во-первых... во-вторых" не остаётся запятых, следовательно, эти элементы располагались **не** в начале каких-л. обособленных оборотов и при возвращении на место требуют обособления на общих основаниях. Отдельно у Розенталя оговорен случай обособления вводных элементов после сочинительных союзов (но, и - п. 5 того же параграфа по ссылке выше):

> Вводное слово (сочетание) *отделяется* от предшествующего
> сочинительного союза (как правило, и, но) запятой, если вводное слово
> *можно опустить* или переставить в другое место предложения без
> нарушения его структуры...
>
> *Терентий пробавлялся мелкой слесарной работой; но, во-первых, работы было мало, и, во-вторых, много времени отнимали неотложные дела.*

Соответственно, обе конструкции "во-первых... во-вторых" в нашем случае должны быть отделены с двух сторон (=обособлены) запятыми.